# Spring Boot on Google Cloud SQL - org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When I run my program in localhost connecting remotely to Google Cloud SQL (MySQL), it works. All the necessary IAM permission are in place once the program is deployed in the Google App Engine, it causes the error:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set. Logs Below:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]     ... 41 common
>   frames omitted

POM File:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.myapi</groupId>
 <artifactId>myapi</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>myapi</name>
 <description>My API</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>

  <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>myapi:asia-south1:myapidb</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
  <user>root</user>
  <password>complicated password</password>
  <database>myapidb</database>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   &lt;!&ndash;<version>8.0.8-dmr</version>&ndash;&gt;
  </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.42</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>-->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.63</version>
  </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>



  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
   &lt;!&ndash;<version>1.0.4</version>&ndash;&gt;
   <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>23.6-jre</version>
  </dependency>


  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>


  <!--dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
  </dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
  </dependency>-->


 </dependencies>

 <!--<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>-->
 <!--<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-milestones</id>
   <name>Spring Milestones</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>-->
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you update your question posting the part of the `pom.xml` file pointing to the connection to Cloud SQL, [as explained in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#code_sample_overview)? See the answer by @MikeE for more information. Also which library and version are you using for the connection? [The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql#setting-up) suggests `mysql-socket-factory v1.0.5`.

Comment: @dsesto i did the edit as you requested. For the socket factory I tried both v1.0.5 and v1.0.4 I also left out the dependencies I tried and commented it out when it didn't worked for me to show you the dependencies I have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not myself worked with Spring Boot and Cloud SQL, but according to some external sources like ***[A]*** or ***[B]***, you should have a file called `application.properties` in the directory `src/main/resources` of your application, and there, you should set some *spring* properties like:

```
database=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<DB_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
spring.datasource.username=<USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password=<PASSWORD>
```

Make sure that you are setting the names properly in this `application.properties` file, and also in the `pom.xml` file.

---

- ***A*** - [Community Tutorial on how to run Spring Boot with Cloud SQL on
  GAE Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-spring-petclinic-on-app-engine-cloudsql)
- ***B*** - [Guide on how to connect to Cloud SQL using Spring](https://medium.com/@DazWilkin/google-cloud-sql-4-ways-spring-a4f13ad32714)

Comment: You are right. The application.properties file read when i deploy it to the Google Cloud Platform should be on src/main/resources. I don't know why but when i'm on my local machine, the one that works is actually the application.properties file in the root directory instead. I don't know the reason why but for now I will keep two application.properties file, one for local dev machine and one for deployment. Now I feel so silly that the solution was so simple.

Comment: Don't worry, I am glad I could help! According to the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) all application/library resources should be located under `src/main/resources`. However, you may have some common application properties at a higher level, and for some reason in how you have set up your configuration, it may be that you are not overriding those properties. However, if you feel like it would be worth, maybe you should post a new question regarding that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC connection string is probably incorrect for App Engine, and Hibernate is unable to figure out the dialect automatically. Note that the connection string for connecting locally is different than when running on App Engine. [See docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/using-cloud-sql-mysql).

```
  <system-properties>
    <property name="cloudsql" value="jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}?user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
    <property name="cloudsql-local" value="jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?useSSL=false&amp;cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}" />
  </system-properties>
```

Also, since you are using Spring Boot, you might want to consider using [Spring Cloud GCP](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/) for connecting to Cloud SQL, which has support for automatically detecting App Engine and generating the correct connection string.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was nothing to do with the hibernate setup.

In the stackdriver's log there was a clear error message to enable the Cloud SQL Admin API:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The Google Cloud SQL API is not enabled for project [<project>]. Please use the Google Developers Console to enable it: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project=<project>
```

A similar error message (as in OP's post) happens when the JDBC URL is wrong and your app can't connect to the Cloud SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>

jdbc:mysql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=<USER_NAME>&password=<USER_PASSWORD>

spring:
    data:
        rest: 
            base-path: /api
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

For the driver use this new one: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver , 
about the SocketFactory, it gets your instances IP address base on the provided cloudSqlInstance